# How to apply CSS to newly loaded Document

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I would like to load a document using `fetch()` and then apply CSS styles to it.

However, it doesn't seem like I can inspect the styles unless I append the document to the main one, as seen here:

```
const doc = fetch(); // get some document

doc.documentElement.computedStyleMap()  // returns an empty map

document.appendChild(doc.documentElement)  // attach it to the main document object

doc.documentElement.computedStyleMap()  // now populated
```

Is there any way I can call some method to get the CSS cascade to happen, populating the computedStyleMap *without* attaching it as done in step 3?

Comment: Please remove the 'Houdini' tag as it's for the VFX software https://www.sidefx.com/products/houdini/

Comment: So you want to get the computedStyles of an element, without having it actually included/attached in the DOM?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to load a document using fetch() and then apply CSS styles to it.

I've tested this locally and it seems computedStyleMap only works for documents / elements that are **actually attached in the** `DOM`.

An alternative is using the styleSheets API.

```
    var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    styleSheet.insertRule('.myclass{ color: 'red'; }', styleSheet.cssRules.length);
```

Keep in mind that if you load a stylesheet from another domain, like a CDN, you may need to select a different index of the `.styleSheets` to use one on your domain. Otherwise you may encounter security errors.